# Azure key vault create in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to programmatically create a key vault in python using this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python). 
No errors till the last step where it throws an exception when I call client.vaults.create_or_update() because I might not have used the right values for ALLOW_OBJECT_ID and ALLOW_TENANT_ID. The documentation says these values can be found on the portal but I could not find it, is there a way to get it programmatically?

Error:
srest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier XXX was not found in the directory YY

Code:

```
import subprocess
import json
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def get_subscription():
    subs = json.loads(subprocess.check_output('az account list', 
                      shell=True).decode('utf-8'))
    subscription = subs[1]['id']
    cmd = 'az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/%s"' % subscription
    creds = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf-8'))
    return subscription, creds

def create_key_vault(vault_name='TestKeyVault'):
    subscription_id, creds = get_subscription()
    client_id = creds['appId']
    secret = creds['password']
    tenant = creds['tenant']
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant)
    client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    ALLOW_OBJECT_ID = client_id
    ALLOW_TENANT_ID = tenant

    RESOURCE_GROUP = 'SomeRG'
    VAULT_NAME = vault_name

    # Vault properties may also be created by using the 
    # azure.mgmt.keyvault.models.VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters
    # class, rather than a map.
    operation = client.vaults.create_or_update(
      RESOURCE_GROUP,
      VAULT_NAME,
      {
        'location': 'eastus',
        'properties': {
            'sku': {
                'name': 'standard'
            },
            'tenant_id': ALLOW_TENANT_ID,
            'access_policies': [{
                'object_id': ALLOW_OBJECT_ID,
                'tenant_id': ALLOW_TENANT_ID,
                'permissions': {
                    'keys': ['all'],
                    'secrets': ['all']
                }
            }]
        }
    }
)

    vault = operation.result()
    print(f'New vault URI: {vault.properties.vault_uri}')
```

Comment: `The documentation says these values can be found on the portal but I could not find it, is there a way to get it programmatically?` If you can find it in the portal, will you also need to do this programmatically? If yes, must in python? Or other languages are also acceptable?

Comment: If I can find it in the portal that's a start but doing it programmatically would be more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the objects could be the users, security groups, service principals in your Azure AD tenant, if you not familiar with access policy in keyvault, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-access-policies).

To get them grammatically, the easiest way in your case is to use Azure CLI in python.

Use [`az account show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-show) to get the `tenantId`.

[image]

Use [`az ad user list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-user-list) to get the `objectId` of the user.

[image]

Use [`az ad group list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-group-list) to get the `objectId` of the security group.

[image]

Use [`az ad sp list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-list) to get the `objectId` of the service principal.

[image]

Then you should specify the `ALLOW_OBJECT_ID` and `ALLOW_TENANT_ID` with the any `objectId` you need and `tenantId` above.